# app_index.html => app is in adminsite to see

Tags: python, django

i have a small problem... i want to bind my app to adminsite. my app doesnot use models.py so the only way to make my app visible in adminsite is to override the app_index.html from django's admin/templates directory. my problem is that i dont know how to override this sothat my app is in admin. i v read all the docs, but the exact way how to do this is hard to find...

here is that app_index.html:

```
{% extends "admin/index.html" %} 
{% load i18n %} 
{% if not is_popup %}

{% block breadcrumbs %}
<div class="breadcrumbs"><a href=".../">
{% trans "HOME" %}</a>  
{% for app in app_list %}
{% blocktrans with app.name as name %} {{ name }} {% endblocktrans %}
{% endfor %}</div>{% endblock %}

{% endif %} 
{% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}
```

thanks in advance...

best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need models.py, just register a "Model" with the admin site.

admin.site.register(class MyMenuThing(models.Model): pass)

Comment: but it doesnot have a model. i want to register by overriding this app_index.html file. i dont need the admin registration. because i dont have a model. in my app, i only use view, not model. thats why, registering my model is nothing here...

Comment: Instead of editing app_index, you register a dummy model that is never syncdb'd. it is completely anonymous and only used to force admin to allocate you space and and url-space for your app. then you override it's urlspace in your urls.conf to point at views in your app.

Comment: At least under py2.7/django 1.6, this results in a syntax error.